# Alternative to the document.createElementNS

Tags: javascript, dom, svg

Help! I tried using

```
document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
```

to create a path childNode for my Svg element but still, I am getting

```
<path></path>
```

instead of

```
<path />
```

I would appreciate if someone could give me an alternative to this method or a workaround

Comment: Why do you want such thing ? the browser will interpret `<path></path>` the same as `<path />` this is just syntaxic sugar

Comment: The browser will display page source however it chooses.  AFAIK there is no way to control that.